# How to secure google Client ID and Client Secret in Angular2 app?

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, config, google-authentication

I'm using google authentication for my angular2 application. I'm using config.js to store google Client ID and Client secret. But the user can get config.js data.

I'm looking for a secure way to handling them. Is there anyway to do this?